# Can't install any new packages with apt-get

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt, imagemagick

From some time I've been getting error messages while installing some packages, for example:

```
requires libmagickwand4 (= 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3) ale 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2 is about to be installed
```

basically there are very small version differences (ubuntu3 vs ubuntu3.2), but I don't know how to fix them. Any help will be welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I've manage to install this packet by specifing what version to install so instead of

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

I've written

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev=8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.2
```

and it worked ;)